# Push telas ionic 3

Tags: ionic, ionic3

Estou utilizando este comando `this.navCtrl.push('HomePage');` para navegar entre as paginas no `ionic 3` porém preciso fazer com que ele não apareça assim o:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não posso da a chance do cara voltar para próxima tela.

Na verdade o que preciso é um `if()` se o usuário ja estiver logado a rootPage é uma se não é outra.

Como fazer isto ?

Tentei fazer assim:

```
export class MyApp {

rootPage:any = LoginPage;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private storage: Storage, platform: Platform, private statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

  platform.ready().then(() => {
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  // statusBar.styleDefault();
  // let status bar overlay webview
  this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
  this.storage.get('cliente').then((val) => {
    if(val != null || val != undefined){
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(RestaurantePage);
    }else{
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
    }
  });

  // set status bar to white
  this.statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString('#ffc107');
  //statusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("ffc107");
  splashScreen.hide();
  });
 }
}
```

Este é o erro:

> Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyApp: ([object Object], ?, [object Object], [object Object], [object Object]).
>       at syntaxError (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:79180:34)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92517:35)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92385:26)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:91994:24)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92638:45)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92624:48
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentsFromProvider (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92623:30)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:92587:83
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>   syntaxError @ VM21376 main.js:79180
>   CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata @ VM21376 main.js:92517
>   CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata @ VM21376 main.js:92385
>   CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata @ VM21376 main.js:91994
>   CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata @ VM21376 main.js:92638
>   (anonymous) @ VM21376 main.js:92624
>   CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentsFromProvider @ VM21376 main.js:92623
>   (anonymous) @ VM21376 main.js:92587
>   CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata @ VM21376 main.js:92551
>   (anonymous) @ VM21376 main.js:92126
>   CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata @ VM21376 main.js:92117
>   JitCompiler._loadModules @ VM21376 main.js:103270
>   JitCompiler.*compileModuleAndComponents @ VM21376 main.js:103229
>   JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ VM21376 main.js:103191
>   PlatformRef*.*bootstrapModuleWithZone @ VM21376 main.js:5141
>   PlatformRef*.bootstrapModule @ VM21376 main.js:5127
>   (anonymous) @ VM21376 main.js:115016
>   **webpack_require** @ VM21376 main.js:48
>   (anonymous) @ VM21376 main.js:140
>   (anonymous) @ VM21376 main.js:143

Comment: Você instalou o plugin e seguiu os passos que diz aqui https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente remover o `navController` e modificar diretamente a variável `rootPage`

```
export class MyApp {

rootPage:any = LoginPage;

  constructor(private storage: Storage, platform: Platform, private statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

  platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
  this.storage.get('cliente').then((val) => {
    if(val != null || val != undefined){
      this.rootPage = RestaurantePage;
    }else{
      this.rootPage = LoginPage;
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: Mesmo erro ainda

Comment: Você removeu o `public navCtrl: NavController`?

Comment: Não deixa testar

Comment: continua Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MyApp:

Answer (score 0):

Se estas a navegar através do teu root component não podes fazer dessa forma.

Exemplo:

```
@Component({
   template: '<ion-nav #myNav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>'
})
export class MyApp {
   @ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController
   public rootPage: any = TabsPage;

   // Wait for the components in MyApp's template to be initialized
   // In this case, we are waiting for the Nav with reference variable of "#myNav"
   ngOnInit() {
      // Let's navigate from TabsPage to Page1
      this.nav.push(Page1);
   }
}
```

[Podes ver mais aqui](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) onde diz: Navigating from the Root component